# What is the number $p(n)$ of partitions of an abundant number $n$ into distinct, proper divisors of $n$?

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

For lack of a better symbol, $p_{\sigma\tau}(n)$ (feel free to suggest something better).

For example, $p_{\sigma\tau}(12) \geq 2$ since $12 = 1 + 2 + 3 + 6 = 2 + 4 + 6$.

Of course if $n$ is deficient then $p_{\sigma\tau}(n) = 0$ and if $n$ is perfect then $p_{\sigma\tau}(n) = 1$. Though there are a few abundant $n$ for which $p_{\sigma\tau}(n) = 0$.

**EDIT:** Earlier I neglected to put in: A suitable partition must have more than one element, so $12 = 12$ doesn't count.

Comment: Presumably you mean divisors of $n$ that are $< n$, otherwise $[n]$ would be an admissible partition of n. In that case, checking shows that you have $p(12)$ = 2.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: Might help: try searching for semi-perfect or pseudoperfect numbers.  These are the numbers for which $p_{\sigma\tau}(n)\ge1$.

Comment: See http://oeis.org/A018818

Comment: the oeis list is for divisors that ned not be distinct. I think Robert wants distinct divisors....Yes, in the title but not repeated in the question body

Comment: There are infinitely many weird numbers weird numbers (abundant $n$ for which $p(n) = 0$) is positive. In fact their asymptotic density, that is, the limit $\lim_{m \to \infty} \#\{n \leq m : n \text{ is weird}\} / m$ is positive (but is known to be bounded above by $\frac{1}{99}$).

Comment: @WillJagy Ah, I didn't notice that they needed to be distinct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly the content of http://oeis.org/A065205 (as Will Jagy kindly points out, the values of $p(n)$ for $n \leq 1000$ are listed in http://oeis.org/A065205/b065205.txt); for the first abundant numbers $n$, $p(n)$ (I'll suppress the suggested subscript) is given by:

$$\begin{array}{cc}
 n & p(n)\\
\hline
12 & 2 \\
18 & 2 \\
20 & 1 \\
24 & 5 \\
30 & 3 \\
36 & 7 \\
\vdots & \vdots
\end{array}$$

The function $p(n)$ can be implemented by the following Mathematica code due to Jean-François Alcover (2012 February 23):

```
a[n_] := (dd = Most[ Divisors[n] ];
    cc = Array[c, Length[dd]];
    Length[ {ToRules[Reduce[
        And @@ (0 <= # <= 1 &) /@ cc && dd . cc == n, cc, Integers]]}]);
```

**Remark** At Will's request, the sequence of successive champions of the sequence $p(n)$ (that is, the $p(n)$ for which $p(n) > p(m)$ for all $m < n$) for $n \leq 1000$, together with their respective $n$, starts
$$\begin{array}{cc}
 n & p(n)\\
\hline
 1 & 0 \\
 6 & 1 \\
12 & 2 \\
24 & 5 \\
36 & 7 \\
48 & 10 \\
60 & 34 \\
120 & 278 \\
180 & 751 \\
240 & 2157 \\
360 & 22208 \\
720 & 676327 \\
840 & 2225346 \\
\end{array}$$

Abundant numbers for which $p(n) = 0$ are precisely the [**weird numbers**](http://oeis.org/A006037); the first of these are
$$70, 836, 4030, 5830, 7192, 7912, \ldots,$$
and there are no odd weird numbers $< 10^{20}$.

As you point out, if $n$ is perfect then $p(n) = 1$, but the converse is not true; the first counterexamples are
$$20, 78, 88, 102, 104, 114, \ldots$$
(see http://oeis.org/A064771 , which includes the perfect numbers too). Odd numbers of this type are rare: The first is $8925$, and there are only four such odd numbers $< 10^8$.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A065205/b065205.txt

Comment: @WillJagy I've included a list of the champions for $n \leq 1000$ (I did this manually using the OEIS list, so I encourage anyone else to verify this). What is the method you have in mind?

Comment: Travis, thanks. I had in mind the Superior Highly Composite numbers and the Colossally Abundant Numbers; the behavior of this problem is unsuitable from your list, I had no idea it grew so quickly. Thanks for the list! For the Ramanujan thing, we need polynomial growth at most.

Comment: You're welcome. And I wish I were, but I'm following it on http://au.eurosport.com/tennis/australian-open-women/2015/alexandra-panova-maria-sharapova_mtc749148/live.shtml Alas, the streams (including ausopen.com) are all region-restricted in Australia...

Comment: Wadim Zudilin of Newcastle sometimes goes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking for a formula for the function, I'm afraid there is no straightforward answer.

Sloane's OEIS tells us that `A065205(n) = A033630(n) - 1.` That leads me to $$p_\sigma(n) = f(n, n, 1) - 1$$ where $$f(n, m, k) =  f(n, m, k + 1) + f(n, m - k, k + 1)0^{n \bmod k}$$ if $k \leq m$, else $0^m$.

(By the way, I think $p(n)$ is too plain and $p_{\sigma\tau}$ a bit excessive).

Comment: I saw the notation $0^{n \bmod k}$ in the OEIS entry but was puzzled; presumably this means $1$ if $n \bmod k$ is $0$ and $0$ otherwise?

Comment: Now I'm confused too. I'll have to sleep on it...

Comment: @Travis, yes, it does. $f(n, m, k)$ counts the number of partitions of $m$ into distinct divisors of $n$ each of which is at least $k$, so the first term on the RHS counts the ones where $k$ is not in the partition, and the second term counts the ones where $k$ *is* in the partition - but obviously it can only be in the partition if it's a divisor of $n$.